# Calculate KDF (just like a hash digest) such as PBKDF2 on command line? using openssl or otherwise

Tags: openssl, hashing, sha-2, digest

OpenSSL can be used to calculate a hash of a file or given input from the shell, like this:

`echo -n "abc" | openssl dgst -sha256`
or
`openssl dgst -sha256 myfile.txt`

Can I also calculate a KDF value, e.g. PBKDF2 or bcrypt or scrypt or Argon2 in a similar way?

So given an input (plaintext or filename) plus the appropriate parameters like iteration count, can I get the corresponding KDF result?

Ideally I'd use `openssl` for this (as it's available on all platforms) but if there is another standardized tool or way of doing this, that's also fine.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I found `nettle-pbkdf2` to be commonly available on both macOS (through Homebrew) as well as Linux (through `apt get`).

`echo -n 'MyPaSsWoRd' | nettle-pbkdf2 --iterations 500000 --length 64 --hex-salt 436d07d286c730ad`

Gives a 64 byte (512 bit) PBKDF2 result, using HMAC-SHA256 as the underlying hashing function.

Comment: On macOS, `brew install nettle`. Unfortunately, `nettle-pbkdf2` doesn't let you pick the hash function, it is hardcoded to HMAC-SHA256.